# Cannot decode utf8 when sending a string from one method to another method, in same file

Tags: python, methods, unicode, utf-8

When I send a string from one method to another in the same file, I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: unexpected end of data`

When I replace the input value to a string in the second method, the function works. When I send the string as a variable, it does not. 
When I put loop into method2, the function works. Is there a encode issue for utf8 and unicode?
When I send a list from method1 to method2, it works. When I send just a string it does not work.

```
def compareTwoFiles(file1Path, file2Path):
    try:
        print(type(file2Path) #result is unicode
        with open(file2Path, "r") as json_file: # does not work
        #with open("./DEV3_export.json", "r") as json_file: # works 
            fileDict = json.load(json_file)
            task_list = fileDict['definition']['tasks']
            for i, task_details in enumerate(task_list):
                task_details = task_list[i]
                print(task_details)


    except IOError as e:
        logging.error(e.message)
    return

def compareFilesInTwoDirectories(serversNameList):
        catchedServerPath = './servers/' + file_name + '_export.json'
        newServersPath = './' + file_name + '_export.json'

        logging.warning(catchedServerPath)
        logging.warning(newServersPath)
        if os.stat(newServersPath).st_size > 0:
            compareTwoFiles(catchedServerPath, newServersPath)
    return 

print(compareFilesInTwoDirectories(serversNameList))
```

Comment: What is the value of `file2path` when the exception happens? And which line raises the UnicodeDecodeError? If you use `logging.exception` instead of `logging.error`, you get the full traceback, which might help answering these questions.

Comment: Btw, this whole `str`/`unicode` confusion is one of the major reason to move from Python 2 to Python 3. You already use Python 3 syntax throughout the code presented (`print()` as a function, `except ... as`), why don't you switch too?

Comment: fixed with io.open

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, by using `io.open` instead of `open`.
    
            `with io.open(file2Path) as json_file:
                fileDict = json.load(json_file)
                task_list = fileDict['definition']['tasks']
                for i, task_details in enumerate(task_list):
                    task_details = task_list[i]
                    print(task_details)`

Comment: One more reason to switch to Python 3, where built-in `open` is `io.open`.